# Linq to XML select ancestors up to 2 levels

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-xml

Given the XML below I need to recurively select the employee who's positions.position.manager_position matches a position parameter.

How can this be achieved with linq to XML?

```
<employee id="0004000">
    <!-- ... -->
</employee>
<employee id="0004001">
     <username>Administrator</username>
     <positions>
      <position id="00008001" isPrimary="1">
       <title>GENERAL MANAGER</title>
       <manager_position>00008431</manager_position>
      </position>
     </positions>
</employee>
<employee id="0004002">
    <!-- ... -->
</employee>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
employees.Where(e => e.Element("positions")
                      .Elements("position")
                      .Elements("manager_position")
                      .Any(mp => mp.Value == position))
```

Select those employees, that have at least one `manager_position` element that matches the posution you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This example will return the matching employee [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340098.aspx) or `null` when none were found:

```
var employees = XElement.Parse(
    "<employees><employee><!-- ... --></employee></employees>");

var results = employees
    .Elements("employee")
    .Where(e => e.Descendants("manager_position").Value == "00008431")
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

**See also:**

- [XContainer.Descendants Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813.aspx)